# Request list of words on Wiktionary API

Tags: api, wiktionary

I'm trying to get a list of random french words from Wiktionary, [using this](https://fr.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&list=random&titles=Main%20Page&rnnamespace=0&rnlimit=10). But words from other languages appear, how can I get only french words?

Comment: Remember the goal of Wiktionary is to document words of all languages. So for example, I found an entry *fraglos* by your query. This happens to be a German word, but it is documented in French Wiktionary and explained in French. The only way I can see to discern that *fraglos* is a word in the German language is to actually visit that page and observe that it says *Allemand* at the top.

Comment: Thanks, I also  see there categories, may be there a way to request category :French or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get more than one entry, but you can get one by leveraging lemma categories and one special page. Those categories all lemmas in a specific language. The special page is called "RandomInCategory".

So for a French word you would need to access this page:
Special:RandomInCategory/French_lemmas